# Can we can add the missing headerfiles in c compiler

Tags: c#

I am not having the sys/utname.h headerfiles in my compiler so .....can any one tell me that we can add the headerfile by downloading that headerfile by internet and how to add in compiler

Answer (score 0):

Your tag you put is incorrect it's C++ not C#. To add a header file you can either directory add it to the project while making sure its in the sys folder. Or specify the directory to it in your project settings.